# rb.addforce not responding even though collision works

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

how are you doing?
I am working on a simple mechanic of knockback where if my character collides with the name "enemy", the players rigidbody which is paraphrsased as (rb), has force added 'back'.

Here is my code, Please refer to where I outline with asterisk.

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public float speed;

private Rigidbody rb;

public int health;
private float knockback;


// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    knockback = 2f;

}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "enemy")
    {
        health = health - 20;  //**this works**
        rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * knockback); //**but this doesnt :c **
    }
}

void death()
{
    if (health <= 0)
    {
        print("i died");
    }
}

void playerWalk()
{
    var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 75f;
    var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 5f;

    transform.Rotate(0, x, 0);
    transform.Translate(0, 0, z);

}
void Update()
{
    death();
    playerWalk();

}
```

}

The problem is as you may have guessed, My triggers do not work.
My health = health - 20; line works but my rb.addforce doesn't.

What could be the problem here? Thank you :)

edit 2#

Just want to edit this and say That I have figured out the problem. The problem was that my float value just was not high enough xD

Comment: can you be more specific in what "my rb.addforce doesn't work" means? Do you get any error or exception? Does this line of code get reached at all? Have you checked if a greater or lower value of ´knockback´ has a different outcome? Have you tried different ´ForceMode´s? Are you aware that, as you wrote, ´rb´ is a local variable inside the Start() method and **not a class field**?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your Rigidbody's inspector.

Comment: Additionally add a Debug.Log line to your OnCollisionEnter line. The problem might be that the collision isn't happening and there are many ways to screw up a collision.

Comment: Hi again :), I have posted my screenshots to imgur, the link is in the last line of my edited question.

Comment: You're sure the Health-20 is working?

Comment: Why did you edit your question to include a deltatime in your force: `rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * knockback);`? I dont think you really mean that. Also, if you edit the contents of your question, you should avise it, because it is becoming rly confusing

Comment: It is all solved now. My float value was just not high enough! Thank you so much for bearing with me, I am a new coder so I make stupid mistakes hehe

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote the snippet, ´rb´ is not a field, but a local variable inside the ´Start´ method. If you are getting an exception in the menctioned line, maybe it is because of this. If you want ´rb´ to be a field, accesible all arround the class methods, you'll need to declare it in the class body, like this:

```
public int health;
private float knockback;
private RigidBody rb;

// (...) the rest of your code
```

If this is not the case, just tell me and give us more info on your problem.

Comment: It is solved now, the float was just not high enoiugh for the knockback variable :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the deltaTime:

```
     rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * knockback);
```

The default [ForceMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html) for `AddRelativeForce` is `AddForce` and does not require time scaling.

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert but this is my answer....
You attached rigidbody to the transform....so changing rigidbody position equal to transform position...
You calling two methods in update...so they going to be continuously called....so you move transform forward direction with uparrow key..  But you add force only at collision enter...collision enter is called only one time but playerwalk method is called continuously...that's why add force is not recognised.... Check this link
http://unityweltech.blogspot.com/2018/09/rbforce-is-not-responding.html?m=1